# Problema com Tomcat - "Obsolete Files from Server"

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

Boa noite!

Hoje a tarde meu computador ficou emotivo e desligou sozinho enquanto eu estava subindo o tomcat. Como eu ia sair, não me importei muito. Contudo, agora que cheguei da faculdade e resolvi continuar meu projeto me deparei com a seguinte mensagem de erro quando tento iniciar o server dentro do eclipse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como posso resolver isso?

Desde já, obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, experimenta limpar a pasta da Configuração do server e do projeto, indo em `Window > Show View > Server`.

Clica com o botão direito sobre o server em seguida `Clean Tomcat Work Directory` e depois `Clean...`, feito isso só dar `Debug`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já tentei isso, amigo. Não deu certo. :/

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se foi o correto, mas acho que solucionei, pois o server voltou a subir...

Troquei a Location dele. Acho que o fato do computador ter desligado acarretou num problema nos Metadados.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]